# How to keep two views centered using AutoLayout

Tags: uikit, autolayout

I have two buttons, which I would like to keep centered in their superview as a group.

Expressed in visual format I want something like `|-*-[button1]-5-[button2]-*-|` where `*` should be equal and be automatically determined by AutoLayout.

I currently have three workarounds which all seem not very elegant

1. make the two buttons subviews of a UIView and center that view
2. calculate the value of `*` manually and manually update the constraints
3. align both buttons to the superview's center with an offset manually calculated from the button widths

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I was focussing too much on aligning the centers of the two buttons to their superview. When I started thinking about the edges instead I came up with this

```
[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:button1
                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight
                             relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                toItem:superview
                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                            multiplier:1
                              constant:-2.5]];

[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:button2
                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                             relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                toItem:superview
                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                            multiplier:1
                              constant:2.5]];
```

This keeps the two buttons centered in `superview` with an intermediate spacing of 5.

Answer (score 0):

You could center a dummy element, (a hidden view) then offset each button to the left and right.

[image]

Comment: Creating another view is something I wanted to avoid. But thanks for the suggestion. I led me to my own answer, see above